# Plotmath symbol and reference to a variable in R plot legend: possible without Unicode character?

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

I am trying to make a label in a base R plot legend that has a greater than or equal to sign followed by a numeric value that is gathered from a variable. I can do this with the following code using the Unicode character, and the `bquote` function:

```
data = c(1,2,3,4)
paste0("\u2265", bquote(.(data[2])))
```

I would like to know if it is possible to make such a label without the Unicode character, while referencing a variable for a numeric value. I have been unsuccessful using combinations of nested `expression`, `paste`, `substitute`, and `bquote` function calls, and I have not seen a question here that addresses this specific issue (I apologize if I missed something).

Ideally, the solution would generalize to other plotmath characters as well.

Comment: bquote(>= .(data[2]))?Either you haven't read help("plotmath") or I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: That results in an error: "unexpected >="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = c(1,2,3,4)

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, bquote({} >= .(data[2])), cex = 30)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: What do the curly brackets add? A small space?

Comment: I think they add nothing but there seems to be a small space added after that nothing.

Comment: This solves my question as asked, but the result, `≥ 2` cannot be stored in a `list`, like a[1] = `bquote({} >= .(data[2]))`. It is interpreted as 3 elements: {}, >=, and 2, and the `≥` is not one of those elements. I realize this is a different problem, so let me know if I should ask a different question, or add to this question.

Comment: Create a vector of mode "expression" and store it within that vector. Or I believe a[[1]]] <- ... could also work if you need a list. I can't test right now.

Comment: I needed to use a vector of mode expression, named `a`, and a[[1]] to get the `≥ 2` to plot correctly. Interestingly, that removes the bold from the ≥, but the 2 is still bold. I'm fine with that, though. Thanks for the help!